# Saving code in database, what are pitfall I should be careful about

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am designing a system which takes user submitted code and saves it in database. Code can be in any language, ruby, python, elixir, javascript, etc. There's no restriction on language. Code saved in database is never meant to be run. It will be displayed in blog article or converted into file for download. Similar example might be [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/discover) or [Cacher](https://snippets.cacher.io), both takes user submitted code and displays on website.

1. How do I make sure User submitted code is sanitised and secure to be displayed on webpage with code highlighter?
2. What processing do I need to do on code such that I can safely display it? I don't want to impose strict restrictions on users.
3. Any gotcha I need to be aware?
4. Any idea how those website implement this feature?

   I am using Elixir and Phoenix framework. Is there any pitfalls I should be careful about? I am thinking of using `Phoenix.HTML` module to escape codes. I just wanna be sure that my approach doesn't have known loop holes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Henna, I am not sure why your question has been downvoted, but if I may, I would like to tell you: as such, your question is too broad, and is likely to generate answers that goes into too many directions. Try to narrow the subject, and give a concrete example of what you have done so far.

Comment: thanks for suggestion @NathanRipert, I have updated the question. Hope it makes it little more clear.

Comment: Well even with rewording your question it’s still a pretty broad question. Sorry—vote to close.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet